# Download from Azure storage in html link

Tags: html, azure, azure-storage

So I have a file uploaded to my azure storage and have a simple anchor tag where a user should be able to simply download the file. This is not working and not understanding why.

My code:

```
<a href="https://cembsite.file.core.windows.net/cembapphandouts/IsraelHandouts/Solution Interview Worksheet.pptx">Get Worksheet Here!</a>
```

When you click on the link to download, it takes to an error saying invalid http header. This is a simple powerpoint file. If I go to the file properties within Azure, I can click download and it does fine.

Any thoughts to how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your URL is pointing to Azure File storage, which is not quite the same as raw blobs. That is, you cannot just access individual files within the Azure File store without proper authentication (e.g. mounting the smb volume, using the API, Shared Access Signature, etc), even though File Storage is backed by blob storage.

If you truly stored the object in a blob (vs File Storage), then the url should look something like:

```
https://cembsite.blob.core.windows.net/containername/filename.pptx
```

Notice the URL contains `blob` vs `file`.

Comment: Where do I make sure I store it there versus where I have it?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking but... it's totally up to you, whether you store content in a File Store volume or in discrete blobs. How you do that is out-of-scope for your question (and unrelated to my answer, which is just focused on showing you that your URL is not going to work). Also, I can't even tell, based on your comment, whether you're currently using File Storage or direct blob storage.

Comment: I figured it out. I chose file rather than blob. All works now. Thanks for pointing that out.