# How to Download remote image file?

Tags: php, azure, download

I want to download my image and pdf etc files from my azure blob storage. I tried with this code it gives me blank files.can anyone help? here is my code. my url is like.https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/68-documents/15347493127361.png. I am geting it by tag from html.

```
    set_time_limit(0);

    $url = $this->input->get("url");
    $file = basename($url);

    $fp = fopen($file, 'w');

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
```

I changed my code like this still not working

```
set_time_limit(0);
$url = 'https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/68-documents/15347493127361.png';
$file = basename($url);
$data = file_get_contents($url);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file) . "\"");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($data));
header("Connection: close");
?>
```

Comment: You never use your `$data` var. You need something like `file_put_contents($file, $data);` after curl_exec

Comment: Excuse, did not read your question carefully. I have added an aswer, but that is `HTML` related. I am not sure with `azure`. Can you modify it like HTML? If that is the case, I can show you the answer.

Comment: @RonnieOosting I tried with html5 download tag it is not working

Comment: Would this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917730/download-from-azure-storage-in-html-link